# Заливка скрипта с одного фтп на другой на php

Tags: php, ftp

Уважаемые коллеги. На моем хостинге расположены несколько сайтов - соответственно в корне фтп такое же число папок. Мне нужен скрипт на PHP (точнее, даже подсказка, как такое  написать), который бы брал файл из одной папки фтп и копировал его в указанную. Почему-то я с функциями ftp_get/ftp_put и их разновидностями не могу этого достичь.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, просто:

$pathw = "ftp://".$config['ftp_user'].':'.$config['ftp_pass'].'@'.$config['ftp_serv']."/site_folder/www/m.php";

$cont=file_get_contents('___shorter.php');

if(file_put_contents($pathw, $cont)) echo "It worked!!!";

Comment: а еще проще php не использовать))